# If we have $\mu_{xy}$, why can we only construct the spectral measure if $\| \mu_{xy} \| \le \| x \| \|y \|$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

**Definitions**

*Representation*

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^N$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra in $\mathcal{C}(X)$. Also, we denote $L(H)$ as the set of all linear operators on HIlbert space $H$.

We call $\Phi : \mathcal{A} \ni u \rightarrow \Phi(u) \in L(H)$ a representation, if:

1. $\Phi$ is linear and multiplicative
2. $\Phi(e) = I_H$, where $e$ is the neutral multiplicative element of the algebra $\mathcal{A}$
3. There exists a $K > 0$ such, that $\| \Phi(u) \| \le K \|u \|$ for all $u \in \mathcal{A}$

*Measure $\mu_{xy}$*

A measure $\mu_{xy}$ is called the "elementary measure for $\Phi$", if for any $x,y \in H$:

$$\langle \Phi(u) x, y \rangle = \int_X u(z) d\mu_{xy}$$ for $\| \mu_{xy} \| \le K \| x \| \|y \|$.

*Spectral measure*

On a Borel set $\mathcal{B}$ in $\Omega$, we call $E : \mathcal{B} \ni \Delta \rightarrow E(\Delta) \in B(H)$ a spectral measure, if:

1. $E(\Omega) = I_H$, $E(\varnothing) = 0$
2. $E(\Delta)$ is an orthogonal projection in $H$ for all $\Delta$
3. $E(\bigcup_{n}^{\infty} \Delta_n) = \sum_{n}^{\infty} E(\Delta_n)$ for all disjunctive $\Delta_n$

**Important:** In this context, we will assume, that $\Phi$ is a natural representation ("functional calculus") of an $N$-tuple of operators $(T_1, \ldots, T_N)$, i.e.

$$\Phi(u) := u(T_1, \ldots, T_n)$$

---

Now to the question: If we have $\mu_{xy}$, why can we only construct the spectral measure (for the operator tuple $(T_1, \ldots, T_N)$), if $\| \mu_{xy} \| \le \| x \| \|y \|$ (and thus $K = 1$)?

We know that we then have:

$$\mu_{xy} (\Delta) = \langle E(\Delta) x, y \rangle$$

But why is the assumption of $\| \mu_{xy} \| \le \| x \| \|y \|$ necessary?

We construct it by defining $q_{\Delta} (x,y) := \mu_{xy} (\Delta)$ and then using the Riesz-Frechet theorem (i.e. there exists an operator $A$ such, that $q_{\Delta} (x,y) = \langle A x, y \rangle$). Is the assumption $\| \mu_{xy} \| \le \| x \| \|y \|$ necessary here somehow?

I thought that it might be because then, $\|E (\Delta) \| \le K$ and we don't have a guarantee that $\| E (\Delta) \| \le 1$ (as it should be if $E(\Delta)$ should be a projection). But I was talking to my professor (I'm a 1st year PhD student) and indeed, he told me that it may become a problem if $\| \mu_{xy} \| \le K \| x \| \| y \|$ if $K > 1$, but the main problem would be to prove that $E(\Delta) = E(\Delta)^*$ and $E(\Delta)^2 = E(\Delta)$ under these assumptions (then $E(\Delta)$ would be a projection and $\| E(\Delta) \| \le 1$, which does not stand in contradiction to what we got i.e. $\|E (\Delta) \| \le K$).

My question would be: But why is $K = 1$ important here?

Comment: In the sentence "We call $\Phi \colon \mathcal{A} \ni u \to \Phi(u) \in L(H)$, if: [conditions]," is there a word missing?

Comment: @Vectornaut Yes. "We call $\Phi : \mathcal{A} \ni u \rightarrow \Phi(u) \in L(H)$ a representation, if: [conditions]"